# Iterating over a list with one element removed each time

Tags: python, list, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a list `nums` with one of its elements (let's say `x`) removed each time.

I can't do it using `list.remove(x)` because this is not an iterable.

If I make another list comprehension `[n for n in nums if n != x]`, this will remove all the elements that match `'y'` not just the first one.

So instead, I've sliced everything until the first time the element is found and then everything after that, using `nums[:nums.index(x)]+nums[nums.index(x)+1:]`

Is there a prettier or more efficient way to do this?

---

For additional background, I started thinking about this while working on a list comprehension expression   (which I'm sure is itself not the most efficient bit of code):

```
[x for x in nums if target - x in nums[:nums.index(x)]+nums[nums.index(x)+1:]]
```

Comment: Why won't `nums.remove(x)` remove x from nums?

Comment: you need to provide input samples and desired output

Comment: Why not just `nums = nums[:nums.index(x)]+nums[nums.index(x)+1:]`?

Comment: @DarrylG it does, but I'm looking to iterate over it and that's not iterarable

Comment: @Nick I'm curious if there's a better or more pythonic way?